# How to do internationalization of ionic app name for windows platform

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, internationalization

How can I accomplish this? I know there is a `<name>` label in config.xml file of ionic project, and it is the one I should work out. My ionic project's platform is windows 10. Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This will solve your problem:

https://doylestowncoder.com/2016/04/13/cordova-hook-internationalizing-your-app-name-for-android/

http://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2012/02/internationalization-of-app-names/ (ios localization)